# How To Make Two Container Heights Match?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a Twitter-Bootstrap site that has two columns: a narrow side column and a main article column. On each page, the widths of the columns are fixed and the heights depend on how much is inside them. The side column's height always must match the main column's, but the main column's height is variable. On some pages, the main column is short because there aren't many articles inside while on other pages its height is much longer. When the main column's height is taller than the side column's, the side column's increases.

My question is, what are the best methods/technologies to implement this, without using a CMS? I'm thinking classes, maybe something along the lines of masonry CSS...but not quite sure where to start. For the smaller-screen version, I'm planning to align them as just one column, so this won't need to be fully responsive.

I've prepared a crude drawing of what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

Comment: My first question would be: What do you want to happen if the Side column is longer than the main column? i.e. Do you want the main column height to expand to match the side column height if it is smaller?

Comment: Good question. The side column will never be larger than the main column. At a minimum, both column's height will be 800px.

Comment: in that case the flex answers below will do the job!

Comment: **Joansy** Hi there, If you as you say on small screen you want single column. If that is the case, then you will not want all that empty space when these two blocks stack. As the second will go below the first. So there is not much point in having the first column match the height of the second column. Try to consider how this will look on all screen sizes and when ... which screen size you want them to stack. How do you also want the narrow column to look when full width.

Comment: Why did  I get a downvote on this?

Comment: @AngularJR I think what I'll do is have the main column be col-sm-12 and sit on top of the side column. Because the side column is secondary, I want readers to view it after the main content. Thanks for helping me brainstorm! :)

Comment: Hi there, Your welcome. Glad to try and help to look at the bigger picture.  By the way.. It wasn't me that down voted. I always think that if someone does that they should say why. All the best.

Comment: **Joansy**, if you wanted to still have the narrow first block show on the left on large screen but remove it and display it second you could consider using the classes `hidden-xx` to juggle the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get away with it, I would recommend using [flex box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).  If not, here is a CSS solution http://plnkr.co/edit/geevZTdUy4PDEJqvNHmp?p=preview

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row eq-row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 eq-col red">This is the first col</div>
      <div class="col-xs-8 eq-col blue">
        This is the main col<br />
        This is the main col<br />
        This is the main col<br />
        This is the main col<br />
        This is the main col<br />
        This is the main col<br />
        This is the main col<br />
        This is the main col<br />
        This is the main col<br />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here's the CSS.

```
.red
{
  background-color: red;
}

.blue
{
  background-color: blue;
}

.eq-row
{
  overflow: hidden;
}

.eq-col
{
  margin-bottom: -99999px;
  padding-bottom: 99999px;
}
```

Comment: I returned to choose this one as the best answer because it proved to be the easiest to implement at different screen sizes. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

So, you can use flex-box for this. Your HTML would look something like this:

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-column">
        <!-- Left column content goes here -->
    </div>
    <div class="flex-column">
        <!-- Longer right column content goes here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

And your CSS:

```
.flex-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-container > .flex-column {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Support for flexbox is limited, but it is the best solution for you here. http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

**UPDATE:**

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yeqkmkuj/) showing the implementation in action.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the flexbox option - which I'd definitely go for it if I wouldn't want full cross-browser compatibility -, you can use some JavaScript or jQuery to set the side height if it's smaller than the content height.

See it in action [here](http://www.bootply.com/0vKdgKMiRg)! You can try it by removing dummy text from the content etc.

JavaScript:

```
var contentHeight = document.getElementById('content').offsetHeight;
var sideHeight = document.getElementById('side').offsetHeight;

if (contentHeight > sideHeight) {
  document.getElementById('side').style.height=contentHeight+'px';
}
```

> The **HTMLElement.offsetHeight** read-only property is the height of the element including vertical padding and borders, in pixels, as an integer.

There is also clientHeight, which you could use depending on the case, which is:

> The **Element.clientHeight** read-only property returns the inner height of an element in pixels, including padding but not the horizontal scrollbar height, border, or margin.

jQuery:

```
var contentHeight = $(".content").height();
var sideHeight = $(".side").height();
var side = $(".side");
if (contentHeight > sideHeight) {
  side.height(contentHeight);
}
```

Comment: Wow! I just forked it, you can see here this is EXACTLY what I was looking for: http://www.bootply.com/H8RBsZjtWY Looks like Flexbox has a lot of browser bugs. Thank you so much, your Javascript works like a charm, I just adjusted the CSS classes. :)